Kendo Editor CreateLink() Unlink() dialog box is not editable
I'm creating a kendo editor and in that I have few tools. Everything is working perfectly normal except the CreateLink().Unklink() function which opens up a dialog wherein we can provide some text. That alone is not working and I tried searching google read the official docs and did every possible research but didn't get the luck.
Please help me with this.

Above is the kendo Editor with the top right tools section in which second last one is the createlink().Unlink() button.

Above is the place where nothing is editable.
Please do let me know what could be the problem,
Here is the code I used to create this KendoEditor.
 @(Html.Kendo().Editor()
                          .Name("EditContactFolderFileDescription")
                          .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control ", @styles = "padding-left: 3px;" })
                          .Tools(tools => tools
                                    .Clear()
                                    .InsertUnorderedList()
                                    .InsertOrderedList()
                                    .CreateLink().Unlink()
                                    .CustomButton(cb => cb.Name("insertFile").ToolTip("Attach File")
                                    .Exec(@<text>
                                            function(e) {
                                            $(".EditAttachmentFile").trigger("click");
                                            e.stopPropagation();
                                            e.preventDefault();
                                            }
                                        </text>))
                                ).Value(@Model.ContactFolderFileDescription).Encode(false)
                        )

Do let me know if you need more information. Thanks.
